# storing a command as an icon in the ubuntu dock

Tags: gnome, scripts, dock

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and I just found out an awesome screenshot tool `flameshot`, the problem is, it has to be invoked by the terminal command `flameshot gui`, and everytime opening the terminal is a hassle, hence I'd like to store this command as an icon in the ubuntu dock, so I can click to invoke this. I think this should be possible, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***for APT Install:***

copy the `flameshot.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` with below command..

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/flameshot.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

then open the file with below command

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/flameshot.desktop
```

and edit the content to match below content..

```
Exec=flameshot gui
```

Then open all apps and choose Flame shot to Add to Favorites..

[image]

[image]

***for SNAP Install:***

The `flameshot` installed by `snapd` is in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` , open the flameshot file there with superuser priviledges and edit the line from:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/flameshot_flameshot.desktop /snap/bin/flameshot
```

to this:

```
 Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/flameshot_flameshot.desktop /snap/bin/flameshot gui
```

now, launching from the icon works, if the icon itself doesn't appear in the menu, then do what is mentioned with in link: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1158993/739431)

Comment: my flameshot isn't located in : /usr/share/applications/flameshot.desktop it seems to be in /snap/bin/flameshot and doesn't have a .desktop there , and at /snap/bin/flameshot which I found by whereis flameshot, it seems there is only a simlink to the actual binary somewhere I don't know

Comment: `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` can you check in this path? I did not knew you installed flameshot as a snap package..

Comment: flameshot is there but it doesn't have a .desktop extension, and is like this `flameshot(Snappy edition)`

Comment: I followed the linked post, but it doesn't display an icon in the dock when I hit `flameshot gui`

Comment: Is the app showing in All apps (when you click show apps button) add that as favourites..

Comment: Ok.. I am trying to install flameshot as a snap package.. give me a moment..

Comment: yes, and I was able to add to favorites, but, it doesn't run from the dock, I think that the problem is that `flameshot` cannot be run with the command `$> flameshot` but with the command `$> flamshot gui`, so , when we click on the dock, the former command gets launched , is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: Ok.. I have tried it in arch linux and yes its not working.. I will try to install Ubuntu 20.04 and see..

Comment: I just found a solution though, I have posted an answer, thanks for the help, should I merge my answer in yours?

Comment: Yours Answer looks great!!!

Comment: yea, but I never mentioned, if I had snapd package or ubuntu

Comment: I just merged it since accepting both the answers were impossible. :-) hope you approve it

Comment: BTW, do you think iconifying shell scripts is possible?

Comment: sorry no idea..